# PHP error page problem

Tags: php

I can't figure out why this script isn't working.

```
<?php

if (($_GET['p'] != 'index') && 
    ($_GET['p'] != 'reg') && 
    ($_GET['p'] != 'login') && 
    ($_GET['p'] != 'ad') && 
    (!isset($_GET['p']))):
?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to not display the error page if the $_GET is not set, which in my experience (`!isset($_GET['p'])`) should do.

Comment: Really? The R-word? Is this third grade?

Comment: You might want to rephrase your title to provide a more accurate description of the problem. A better description will attract more and better answers !

Comment: If you're wanting to check an `!isset($_GET['p'])`, put it first in the list BEFORE checking equality.

Comment: Also, I don't know why you have so many parentheticals grouping single conditions. They're superfluous to what is happening.

Comment: By _"$_GET is not set"_ Do you mean you want `!isset($_GET['p'])` to evaluate to `TRUE` when the get request is like this `?` or when it is `?p=`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `$_GET['p']` is not set, you can't check `$_GET['p'] != 'index'` and all the others. You'll have to check if it's set first:

```
<?php if(
    ! isset( $_GET['p'] ) ||
    ($_GET['p'] != 'index' &&
    $_GET['p'] != 'reg' &&
    $_GET['p'] != 'login' &&
    $_GET['p'] != 'ad')
): ?>
```

---

A better solution would be to put all those values in an array, and check if `$_GET['p']` is in the array:

```
<?php if(
    ! isset( $_GET['p'] ) ||
    ! in_array(
        $_GET['p'],
        array('index', 'reg', 'login', 'ad')
    )
): ?>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Now that you provided some more info, here's what you should do:

```
if ( ! isset($_GET['p']) )
{
    // We're at the index page, so don't display anything
}
else
{
    if ( in_array( $_GET['p'], array('index', 'reg', 'login', 'ad') ) )
    {
        // Display your content window
    }
    else
    {
        // $_GET['p'] is not a valid value, display error
    }
}
```

Comment: i copied your code straight from your comment and it still doesn't work, i even did arrays before and it just doesn't work, It does work when i check if the GET is a certain value, but not if it's not set at all

Comment: I don't understand - if you check if $_GET['p'] is null or empty, why you need other conditions to check values from that variable? If $_GET['p'] is null or empty then it doesn't contain values...

Comment: @evilone - As far as I understand the OP, this is what he's trying to do: If no value was passed as `$_GET['p']`, or `$_GET['p']` is not equals to any of those values, then he glides through. Otherwise, he wants to issue an error.

Comment: I have a page where it checks if a $_GET is set with a certain value, for example if it's Hello then it displays a content window with the text "Hello". But i want nothing to be displayed on the Index, where no $_GET is set, and the Error page to be displayed when the $_GET value does not match any set value.

Comment: @JosephSilber Yeah. that is what i want.

Comment: @JosephSilber You can omit the else statement altogether by changing the if statement to `if ( isset($_GET['p']) )`, and move all the code inside else statement onto the if.

Comment: @Shef - True, but he might also be interested in displaying info specific to the index page, in which case you need that additional if/else statement...

Comment: Thank you all very much, my problem has been solved and now i can continue working :) love you haha :P

Answer (score 4):

Your condition makes no sense. You're checking for 3 possible values of `$_GET['p']` and then checking if `$_GET['p']` is even set. Reverse your logic:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['p']))
    {
        // display error page
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if $_GET['p'] is set by

```
if(isset($_GET['p']) {...}
```

If it's set and not empty then you can check for values that you need to check.

Comment: i have tried !$_GET['p'], !isset, setting a variable when it's set, putting it in a different if statement both before And after the long list of if's, and Nothing seems to work.. the get looks like this in the address bar: ?p=index, and i just can't seem to get it to work

Comment: @albinlennstrand Are you sure that $_GET['p'] is empty when you think it's empty?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$defaultvalue=0; // for example 0
$p=isset($_GET["p"]) ? $_GET["p"] : $defaultvalue;
if(($p != 'index') && ($p != 'reg') && ($p != 'login') && ($p != 'ad')): 
?>
```

Comment: worked just like the old script, it works if the certain values are set but not if it's not set at all :( i appreciate your help tho